# How to use file test to check if a file already exists in a directory

Tags: bash, shell-script

I'm trying to write a script that asks the user if they are sure they want to move a file to a certain directory. The script needs to check if the file already exists in the target directory and if it so, then asks the user if they want to overwrite the existing file with the one they are trying to move.

How should the file test in my if statement look? At the moment I have

if [[ -e /targetdirectory ]] ; then........

but that doesn't seem to be the right solution?

Comment: `mv -i` does the prompt thing for you...

Answer (score 1):

The test you are looking for is:

`[[ -f /path/to/file ]]`

where `/path/to/file` is the path to the file you are testing to see if it exists. You can place this test in a conditional using (provided `DEST_DIR` is the destination directory for the file `SRC_FILE`):

```
if ! [[ -f DEST_DIR/file ]]; then
  mv SRC_FILE DEST_DIR
fi
```

where `!` returns true is the file does **not** exist. This will move the `SRC_FILE` to `DEST_DIR` if it does **not** already exist in `DEST_DIR`.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
if [ -e filename ]; then 
# something
fi
```

**with just one square bracket**

Comment: 2 brackets is fine for `bash` and even helps when there are special characters in a filename, especially if the name is stored in a variable